# Find the powerest of a set recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, printing, powerset

I am trying to find the powerset of a set recursively and then print the results which I am very stuck on any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getpowerset(int a[],int n, ArrayList<String> power){
    if(n<0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if(n==0)
    {
        if(power==null)
            power=new ArrayList<String>();
        power.add(" ");
        return power;
    }

    power=getpowerset(a, n-1, power);
    ArrayList<String> tmp=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s:power)
    {
        if(s.equals(" "))
            tmp.add(""+a[n-1]);
        else
            tmp.add(s+a[n-1]);
    }

    power.addAll(tmp);
    return power;
for (int i = 0; i<power.size();i++){
    System.out.println(power);
    }
```

Comment: You should describe what your code is currently doing. Include expected and actual output if applicable. Also, you have code after your (unconditional) return statement which is never valid in Java (or there's something else that's weird going on there) - please provide a compilable code sample or, if you're asking about a compiler error, also include that error, or, if you know the code won't work, write pseudo-code or a high-level description instead of or in addition to actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Try to think recursively:

- base case) The powerset of an empty set is an empty set
- rec. case) The powerset of a list such [`firstElemnt`] + `restOfTheList` is the powerset of `restOfTheList` plus each element of the powerset of `restOfTheList` chained with `firstElemnt`

**Example:**

Given a list [a,b,c]:

- the powerset of []      -> [[]]  (set with an empty set)
- the powerset of [a]     -> [[], **[a]**] (added `a` to each element of previous powerset)
- the powerset of [a,b]   -> [[], [a], **[b], [a,b]**] (added `b` to each element of previous powerset)
- the powerset of [a,b,c] -> [[], [a], [b], [a,b], **[c], [a,c], [a,b,c]**]  (added `c` to each element of previous powerset)

**ALGORITHM**

```
public static List<List<String>> powerset(final LinkedList<String> originalSet) {
    final List<List<String>> powerset = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
    //Base case: empty set
    if ((originalSet == null) || (originalSet.size() == 0)) {
        final List<String> set = new ArrayList<String>();
        //System.out.println(set);
        powerset.add(set);
    } else { 
        //Recursive case:
        final String firstElement = originalSet.removeFirst();
        final List<List<String>> prevPowerset = powerset(originalSet);
        powerset.addAll(prevPowerset);
        //Add firstElement to each of the set of the previuos powerset
        for (final List<String> prevSet : prevPowerset) {
            final List<String> newSet = new ArrayList<String>(prevSet);
            newSet.add(firstElement);
            //System.out.println(newSet);
            powerset.add(newSet);
        }
    }
    return powerset;
}
```

**TEST**

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final LinkedList<String> originalSet = new LinkedList<String>();
    originalSet.add("a");
    originalSet.add("b");
    originalSet.add("c");
    System.out.println("The powerset of " + originalSet + " is:");
    System.out.println(powerset(originalSet));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The powerset of [a, b, c] is:
[[], [c], [b], [c, b], [a], [c, a], [b, a], [c, b, a]]
```

Note that i have imported the following classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
```